# MySQL - Collecting related rows from another table

Tags: database, mysql

I have three tables, that are like:

```
users
---------------
id
etc...

badges
---------------
id
title
etc...

badges_data
---------------
badge_id
user_id
```

What I'm trying to do is select a set of about 100 users, and also grab all the badges they have, and show them next to their respective users.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 select 
   users.*,
   group_concat(badges.id, '=', badges.title separator ';') as badges_info
 from users
 left  join badges_data on badges_data.user_id=users.id
 inner join badges on badges.id=badges_data.badge_id
 group by users.id
 limit 100;
```

The above will return data like

```
 user.*, 
 badges_id=title;badges_id=title; ...
```

If you think the format returned by group_concat is difficult to read/parse

```
 select 
   users.*,
   badges.*
 from users
 left  join badges_data on badges_data.user_id=users.id
 inner join badges on badges.id=badges_data.badge_id
```

this will return multiple rows for same user if the user has multiple badges